# asp mvc with nvelocity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nvelocity

I am trying use NVelocity with ASP.NET MVC, but I am having difficulty navigating the noise of out-of-date information.  There are many broken links, incorrect info, etc.  Is there a guide or howto that works with the current MVC and NVelocity API and distribution mechanisms?

Tia,
-neil

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are referring to the [CastleProject fork of NVelocity](http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/index.html), since the original project on SourceForge hasn't been updated in six years.

Here are some links I found. Note: my Google search words were ASP.NET MVC NVelocity:

**Simplifying ASP.Net - NVelocity**

http://simpable.com/code/nvelocity

**Testing ScottGu: Alternate View Engines with ASP.NET MVC (NVelocity)**

http://www.chadmyers.com/Blog/archive/2007/11/28/testing-scottgu-alternate-view-engines-with-asp.net-mvc-nvelocity.aspx

**Master Pages with NVelocity and ASP.NET MVC** 

http://architectmuse.blogspot.com/2009/06/master-pages-with-nvelocity-and-aspnet.html

**nVelocity in MVCContrib:**
http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib